# Get id of element being dragged in an if statement

Tags: javascript

Hi i'm trying to find a way to determine what element is being dragged which will affect the outcome of the ondrop. I want to add one class if the gold img is selected and add a different class if the silver img selected. I thought something like this might work but nope...

```
 function GoldDragStart(event) {
      event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
      var Type = "Gold";
    }


 function SilverDragStart(event) {
      event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
      var Type = "Silver";
    }



 function allowDrop(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }


function Img_1_Drop(event) {
    if (Type == "Gold") {   
        document.getElementById('GoldSelection').classList.add('GoldSelection1');
            var pic = "https://i.imgur.com/m2NhQQB.png";
            document.getElementById('GoldSelection').src = pic.replace('90x90', '225x225');
            document.getElementById('GoldSelection').style.display='block'; 
    } else if (Type == "Silver") {


document.getElementById('SilverSelection').classList.add('SilverSelection1');
            var pic = "https://i.imgur.com/RevL021.png";
            document.getElementById('SilverSelection').src = pic.replace('90x90', '225x225');
            document.getElementById('SilverSelection').style.display='block';  
    } 
}
```

Comment: could you make a codepen for your sample?

Comment: Consider posting a [*minimal, complete and verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here.